Hot Water Heater Clogged?
I’ve been having a problem with my electric 40gal AO Smith hot water heater. The unit is four years old and was working fine up until a few days ago. This all started when I turned the main water supply to the house off to conduct pressure tests on a shower I’m building. The main water supply was off for about 20 minutes.
I opened a spigot outside hoping to drain water out of the shower pipes. I forgot to flip the breaker on my water heater. The hot water was cold when my wife showered a few hours later. I checked the elements and I had fried them, so they were replaced.
Now with the new elements and thermostats installed, the tank heats the water up perfectly. However, the tap water is lukewarm at best. The water supplied to the heater comes from a well that has hard water. I noticed “kidney stones” coming out when I drained the tank.
I don’t have any leaks in the water lines leaving the hot water heater. Could the outlet pipe be clogged inside the heater? I took the CPVC off that was threaded to the outlet pipe to see if anything was clogged but didn’t see anything.
I’m at wits end but I don’t want to spend the money to replace the heater if I don’t have to. Any other ideas? I’ve checked and the heater is getting like 248 volts, so power supply isn’t an issue. Also, I’ve checks all the ohms on everything along with my wiring. Thank you in advance

The water in the tank is 125°. This was where the original thermostats were set. Yes, tap water being in the shower and all the sinks. The model is a E6-40R45DV 110

If you have shut off valves at sinks/showers, turn off the cold water valve and open the hot water faucet.  Do you get full flow/pressure?

Is it possible that the expansion tank failed? That can cause debris in the line.

I turned off the cold water supply to the tank and the hot water faucets had full pressure.

This heater does not have an expansion tank.

Is the "CPVC" that you mentioned the dip tube that directs incoming cold water to the bottom of the tank? The one that you say "was threaded to the outlet pipe", i.e. to ensure that lukewarm water, at best, is pulled from the bottom of the tank while cold water enters at the top? You may need to turn the house over, or a least swap the two connections, so that you have a cold water heater.

A new water heater fixed this.
